# The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, machine-learning

I got this error and I don't know how to fix .I hope to help me to fix :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 17550
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.ResultActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.SupportPreconditions.checkArgument(SupportPreconditions.java:104)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:296)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer.loadBuffer(TensorBuffer.java:323)
        at com.example.myapplication.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.kt:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is my code:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.myapplication.ml.HeartDisease
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var textView : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

        textView  = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        var myintent :  Intent = intent

        val v1 = myintent.getIntExtra("v1",0)
        val v2 = myintent.getIntExtra("v2",0)
        val v3 = myintent.getIntExtra("v3",0)
        val v4 = myintent.getIntExtra("v4",0)
        val v5 = myintent.getIntExtra("v5",0)
        val v6 = myintent.getIntExtra("v6",0)
        val v7 = myintent.getIntExtra("v7",0)
        val v8 = myintent.getIntExtra("v8",0)
        val v9 = myintent.getIntExtra("v9",0)
        val v10 = myintent.getFloatExtra("v10",0.0f)
        val v11 = myintent.getIntExtra("v11",0)
        val v12 = myintent.getIntExtra("v12",0)
        val v13 = myintent.getIntExtra("v13",0)


        var byteBuffer : ByteBuffer =  ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(13*13)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v1)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v2)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v3)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v4)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v5)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v6)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v7)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v8)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v9)
        byteBuffer.putFloat(v10)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v11)
        byteBuffer.putInt(v12)

               val model = HeartDisease.newInstance(this)

               // Creates inputs for reference.
               val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 13), DataType.FLOAT32)
               inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

               // Runs model inference and gets result.
               val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
               val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

               startActivity(intent)

                // Releases model resources if no longer used.
               model.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: you aren't adding v13 to the buffer

Comment: Please format the error messages also as *code*, not text (edited).